# DRF: JSONField in serializers with TextField in models cause stringification

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-2.x, python-unicode

I am using python 2.7.11

A have a model let's say `Game` that has a TextField that's supposed to store json values. TextField was chosen because the database is shared with hibernate ORM that doesn't support postgres JSONb natively. Thus I have:

models.py:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Game(models.Model):
    settings = models.TextField(default='{}')
```

serializers.py:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    settings = serializers.JSONField()
```

Is there a clean way to handle this, having valid json strings in the database and returning them as json objects through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
import json

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Game(models.Model):
    settings = models.TextField(default='{}')

    @property
    def settings_json(self):
        return json.loads(self.settings)
```

And then in the serializer:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    settings = serializers.JSONField(source="settings_json")
```

Comment: Worked for me :)